# Weird .ASP pages from my non-ASP site generating 404s

Tags: asp.net, 404

In Google Webmaster Tools, I have a huge list of "Not Found" crawl errors (404) with URLs that look like this: `http://www.exclusivevillas.co.za/villa_view.asp?vSeq=82&activitySeq=3&page=3`, seemingly originating from URLs very similar to that (eg `http://www.exclusivevillas.co.za/villa_view.asp?vSeq=82&activitySeq=3&page=4`.

Thing is, the site is WordPress. Has been for almost a year now. Was plain html before that. I don't know where these ASP requests are coming from. And furthermore, the dates these supposed ASP pages requested these other ASP pages, resulting in 404s, are very recent.

What's going on?

Comment: I assume you will find help easier over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @xyious I don't think the WordPress folks would have any luck with this, since it's not related to WordPress at all - it just happens to be a WordPress site that happens to get these hits.

Comment: @xyious This is more of an Apache thing, I think - it has nothing to do with WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this site which seems to grab random pages and display them side by side with other pages. Here's a cached page that refers to your site: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:FFD5X07W3SAJ:www-g.gluetext.com/content/g/grand_daddy_hotel/grand_daddy_hotel.html+villa_view.asp+vseq&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&source=www.google.co.uk

I would guess it is using some sort of URL generating system to try and find pages and it's generated those URLs for your site because they work on other sites.